# Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update doesn't write data into the sheets when triggered by installable trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have data to be read from another sheet (Master Sheet) within a range
`Master!A1:EE2000`
and to be written on a separate sheet (Sheet A) with the same values (no alterations performed) and location.

This is the code I used for the read and write actions (using Sheets API).

```
function SetGetData() {

  //Send Data to Master Spreadsheet
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Retrieving data from all teams.", "Please wait... ⏳", 30);

  //Get Values from B Sheet
  Logger.log("Getting Data from B Sheet.");
  var myssID = scriptproperties.getProperty("ssID");
  var myss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(myssID);
  var sheetno = JSON.parse(scriptproperties.getProperty('TeamSheetNo'));
  var sheetname = sheetno.toString().concat("B")
  Logger.log("-- Sheet Name: " + sheetname);
  var mysheet = myss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var lastcol = mydatarange.getLastColumn();
  var lastrow = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var mydatarangeNotation = sheetname+"!A1:EE"+lastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: "+sheetno+" & Range: "+mydatarangeNotation);
  //var mydata = mysheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).getValues();
  var mydata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(myssID, mydatarangeNotation).values;
  Logger.log("Getting Data Complete!");


  //Sending B Sheet Values to Master Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Sending Data to Master Spreadsheet");
  var masterID = "XXXXXXXX";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  Logger.log("-- Clearing existing data on " + sheetname + " Sheet.");
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: Master & Range: "+mydatarangeNotation);
  //sheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).setValues(mydata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: mydata}, masterID, mydatarangeNotation, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
  Logger.log("Values on Master Spreadsheet has been updated.");


  //Get Data from Master Spreadsheet Back to this Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Retriving data from all Teams.");
  var masterdatarange = ss.getSheetByName("Master").getDataRange();
  var masterlastcol = masterdatarange.getLastColumn();
  var masterlastrow = masterdatarange.getLastRow();
  var masterrangeNotation = "Master!A1:EE"+masterlastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: Master & Range: "+masterrangeNotation);
  //var masterdata= ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).getValues();
  var masterdata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(masterID, masterrangeNotation).values;
  var myssmaster = myss.getSheetByName("Master");
  myssmaster.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("-- Writing data to this spreadsheet Master Sheet.");
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: "+sheetno+" & Range: "+masterrangeNotation);
  //myssmaster.getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).setValues(masterdata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: masterdata}, myssID, masterrangeNotation, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Workload has now been updated.", "Complete! ", 10);

  Logger.log("This spreadsheet Master Sheet has been updated.");
  var timestamp = myssmaster.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log("Timestamp: " + timestamp);

}
```

Everything seems fine if I  run it through Editor or by using a button however, if it runs using Time-driven trigger (every 10 mins), Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update was executed but no data were written, sometimes it does but sometimes doesn't. I have 2 instances of read and 2 instances of write in a single function for one sheet.

I need to transfer data on Sheet A to the Master Sheet make some processing there and transfer the processed data back to Sheet A. See diagram for visuals.
[Data Transfer Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoiUO.png)

I have a total of 20 sheets that perform the same code. I don't know if the Quota was reached because I've got no error in the execution logs.

I tried using `getValues` and `setValues` first but it keeps exceeding execution time due to a large data and that's how I came up using Sheets API.

My main objective is to automatically update Sheet A based on the data in the Master Sheet.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine the whole script from your question. So, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue of `Everything seems fine if I run it through Editor or by using a button however, if it runs using Time-driven trigger (every 10 mins), Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update was executed but no data were written, sometimes it does but sometimes doesn't. I have 2 instances of read and 2 instances of write in a single function for one sheet.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: By the way, about `if it runs using Time-driven trigger (every 10 mins), Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update was executed but no data were written`, in that case, did you confirm the error message? Or, no error occurred?

Comment: I have now updated my question. No error is shown in the execution logs.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your whole script. From your whole script, I confirmed that there are 2 `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update`. Which part is your current issue?

Comment: And, from `I need to transfer data on Sheet A to the Master Sheet make some processing there and transfer the processed data back to Sheet A. See diagram for visuals. Data Transfer Diagram`, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result?

Comment: There are cases that the 2 'Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update' didn't write any data into the sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your current issue, both scripts of `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update` doesn't write values when the script is run with the time-driven trigger. But, when you directly run your script, no error occurs and both scripts of `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update` can write correct values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The picture attached shows the diagram for that.  Let's say I have Sheet A (with Tab A & Tab Master), data from Tab A will be transferred to Tab A  of  Master Sheet (with Tab A,B,C & Tab Master). Tab Master of Master Sheet  will process all data from Tab A,B,C. Then, Data from Tab Master of Master Sheet will be transfered to Tab Master of Sheet A.

Comment: Thank you for replying. That is correct when run with time-driven trigger sometimes it writes but sometimes it doesn't write. I don't know if this is related to quotas because I have almost 20 sheets that run the same code. But all of them don't show any errors.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the details of the relationship between `I don't know if this is related to quotas because I have almost 20 sheets that run the same code.` and your showing script?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related either. Because I'm calling Sheets API on 20 separate sheets with all of them having time-driven triggers.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, in your showing script, it seems that 2 sheets in 2 Google Spreadsheets are used. So, it seems that 4 sheets are used. I cannot understand about `20 separate sheets` and the relationship between `20 separate sheets` and your showing script. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Apologize for my terms as well. I have 20 Google Spreadsheets rather each having 2 sheets used. You may look at this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoiUO.png) for visuals.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between `I have 20 Google Spreadsheets rather each having 2 sheets used` and your showing script. But, I noticed that in your showing script, you are using `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Retrieving data from all teams.", "Please wait... ⏳", 30);` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Workload has now been updated.", "Complete! ", 10);`. I guessed that those scripts might be due to the reason for your current issue. So, when you remove them and test them again.

Comment: By my guess, I proposed 2 modified scripts as an answer. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct and your issue was not resolved, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this in case someone has the same issue and if anyone can explain more in detail how it works. (I'm still a newbie in this programming language and I apologize for my English.)

My code now works as it should whenever the time-driven trigger runs.

I just replaced `sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()` to a Sheets API `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.clear({},masterID,mydatarangeNotation)`

and `myssmaster.getDataRange().clearContent()` to `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.clear({},myssID,"Master!A1:EE5002")`

I think for the action involving read, clear and write data on Google Sheets to work smoothly it should have come from the same service whether using the Apps Script's built-in Sheets service `Spreadsheetapp` or the Sheets API `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values`.

**Modified Script:**

I used Tanaike's 1st modified script (Thanks, Tanaike).

```
function SetGetData() {

  //Send Data to Master Spreadsheet
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Retrieving data from all teams.", "Please wait... ⏳", 30); // Removed

  //Get Values from B Sheet
  Logger.log("Getting Data from B Sheet.");
  var myssID = scriptproperties.getProperty("ssID");
  var myss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(myssID);
  var sheetno = JSON.parse(scriptproperties.getProperty('TeamSheetNo'));
  var sheetname = sheetno.toString().concat("B")
  Logger.log("-- Sheet Name: " + sheetname);
  var mysheet = myss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var lastcol = mydatarange.getLastColumn();
  var lastrow = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var mydatarangeNotation = sheetname + "!A1:EE" + lastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: " + sheetno + " & Range: " + mydatarangeNotation);
  //var mydata = mysheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).getValues();
  var mydata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(myssID, mydatarangeNotation).values;
  Logger.log("Getting Data Complete!");


  //Sending B Sheet Values to Master Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Sending Data to Master Spreadsheet");
  var masterID = "XXXXXXXX";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  Logger.log("-- Clearing existing data on " + sheetname + " Sheet.");
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.clear({},masterID,mydatarangeNotation);    //Modified
  //sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: Master & Range: " + mydatarangeNotation);
  //sheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).setValues(mydata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: mydata }, masterID, mydatarangeNotation, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  Logger.log("Values on Master Spreadsheet has been updated.");


  //Get Data from Master Spreadsheet Back to this Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Retriving data from all Teams.");
  var masterdatarange = ss.getSheetByName("Master").getDataRange();
  var masterlastcol = masterdatarange.getLastColumn();
  var masterlastrow = masterdatarange.getLastRow();
  var masterrangeNotation = "Master!A1:EE" + masterlastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: Master & Range: " + masterrangeNotation);
  //var masterdata= ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).getValues();
  var masterdata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(masterID, masterrangeNotation).values;
  var myssmaster = myss.getSheetByName("Master");
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.clear({},myssID,"Master!A1:EE5002");  //Modified
  //myssmaster.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("-- Writing data to this spreadsheet Master Sheet.");
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: " + sheetno + " & Range: " + masterrangeNotation);
  //myssmaster.getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).setValues(masterdata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: masterdata }, myssID, masterrangeNotation, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Workload has now been updated.", "Complete! ", 10); // Removed

  Logger.log("This spreadsheet Master Sheet has been updated.");
  var timestamp = myssmaster.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log("Timestamp: " + timestamp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just my guess. In your showing script, you are using `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Retrieving data from all teams.", "Please wait... ⏳", 30);` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Workload has now been updated.", "Complete! ", 10);`. In this case, when the script is run with the time-driven trigger, an error like `Exception: Please select an active sheet first.` occurs. I guessed that those scripts might be due to the reason for your current issue. But, in your comment, you say `No error is shown in the execution logs.`. So, this is just my guess.

So, how about removing those lines? The modified script of your showing script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the script of `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast` is removed.

```js
function SetGetData() {

  //Send Data to Master Spreadsheet
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Retrieving data from all teams.", "Please wait... ⏳", 30); // Removed

  //Get Values from B Sheet
  Logger.log("Getting Data from B Sheet.");
  var myssID = scriptproperties.getProperty("ssID");
  var myss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(myssID);
  var sheetno = JSON.parse(scriptproperties.getProperty('TeamSheetNo'));
  var sheetname = sheetno.toString().concat("B")
  Logger.log("-- Sheet Name: " + sheetname);
  var mysheet = myss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var lastcol = mydatarange.getLastColumn();
  var lastrow = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var mydatarangeNotation = sheetname + "!A1:EE" + lastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: " + sheetno + " & Range: " + mydatarangeNotation);
  //var mydata = mysheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).getValues();
  var mydata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(myssID, mydatarangeNotation).values;
  Logger.log("Getting Data Complete!");


  //Sending B Sheet Values to Master Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Sending Data to Master Spreadsheet");
  var masterID = "XXXXXXXX";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  Logger.log("-- Clearing existing data on " + sheetname + " Sheet.");
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: Master & Range: " + mydatarangeNotation);
  //sheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).setValues(mydata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: mydata }, masterID, mydatarangeNotation, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  Logger.log("Values on Master Spreadsheet has been updated.");


  //Get Data from Master Spreadsheet Back to this Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Retriving data from all Teams.");
  var masterdatarange = ss.getSheetByName("Master").getDataRange();
  var masterlastcol = masterdatarange.getLastColumn();
  var masterlastrow = masterdatarange.getLastRow();
  var masterrangeNotation = "Master!A1:EE" + masterlastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: Master & Range: " + masterrangeNotation);
  //var masterdata= ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).getValues();
  var masterdata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(masterID, masterrangeNotation).values;
  var myssmaster = myss.getSheetByName("Master");
  myssmaster.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("-- Writing data to this spreadsheet Master Sheet.");
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: " + sheetno + " & Range: " + masterrangeNotation);
  //myssmaster.getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).setValues(masterdata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: masterdata }, myssID, masterrangeNotation, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  // SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Workload has now been updated.", "Complete! ", 10); // Removed

  Logger.log("This spreadsheet Master Sheet has been updated.");
  var timestamp = myssmaster.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log("Timestamp: " + timestamp);

}
```

or, if you want to directly run your script without the time-driven trigger, how about the following modification? In this modification, when you directly run `SetGetData`, the event object `e` is null. By this, `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast` is run. When `SetGetData` is run by the time-driven trigger, the event object `e` is not null. By this, `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast` is not run.

```js
function SetGetData(e) {

  //Send Data to Master Spreadsheet
  if (!e) SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Retrieving data from all teams.", "Please wait... ⏳", 30); // Modified

  //Get Values from B Sheet
  Logger.log("Getting Data from B Sheet.");
  var myssID = scriptproperties.getProperty("ssID");
  var myss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(myssID);
  var sheetno = JSON.parse(scriptproperties.getProperty('TeamSheetNo'));
  var sheetname = sheetno.toString().concat("B")
  Logger.log("-- Sheet Name: " + sheetname);
  var mysheet = myss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var lastcol = mydatarange.getLastColumn();
  var lastrow = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var mydatarangeNotation = sheetname + "!A1:EE" + lastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: " + sheetno + " & Range: " + mydatarangeNotation);
  //var mydata = mysheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).getValues();
  var mydata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(myssID, mydatarangeNotation).values;
  Logger.log("Getting Data Complete!");


  //Sending B Sheet Values to Master Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Sending Data to Master Spreadsheet");
  var masterID = "XXXXXXXX";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  Logger.log("-- Clearing existing data on " + sheetname + " Sheet.");
  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: Master & Range: " + mydatarangeNotation);
  //sheet.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).setValues(mydata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: mydata }, masterID, mydatarangeNotation, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  Logger.log("Values on Master Spreadsheet has been updated.");


  //Get Data from Master Spreadsheet Back to this Spreadsheet
  Logger.log("Retriving data from all Teams.");
  var masterdatarange = ss.getSheetByName("Master").getDataRange();
  var masterlastcol = masterdatarange.getLastColumn();
  var masterlastrow = masterdatarange.getLastRow();
  var masterrangeNotation = "Master!A1:EE" + masterlastrow;
  Logger.log("Get Data: SS: Master & Range: " + masterrangeNotation);
  //var masterdata= ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).getValues();
  var masterdata = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(masterID, masterrangeNotation).values;
  var myssmaster = myss.getSheetByName("Master");
  myssmaster.getDataRange().clearContent();
  Logger.log("-- Existing data has been cleared. Proceeding with setting values.")
  Logger.log("-- Writing data to this spreadsheet Master Sheet.");
  Logger.log("Set Data: SS: " + sheetno + " & Range: " + masterrangeNotation);
  //myssmaster.getRange(1,1,masterlastrow,masterlastcol).setValues(masterdata);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: masterdata }, myssID, masterrangeNotation, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  if (!e) SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Workload has now been updated.", "Complete! ", 10); // Modified

  Logger.log("This spreadsheet Master Sheet has been updated.");
  var timestamp = myssmaster.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log("Timestamp: " + timestamp);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tanaike for this. I have figured it out but not quite sure how exactly.